# Django translation doesn't work

Tags: python, django, settings, translation

I'm trying to use django translation, but nothing happens. I can't find my mistake. Could anyone please help me?

Some Details:
I've added LocaleMiddleware;
I've added the context_processors;
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br';
LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
    ('en', 'English')
);
LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')];
My django.po e .mo are created and looks correctly.
Some suggestion?

Comment: What is the problem of my question? What is the reason for the negative point?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

how did you load the translated page?

Comment: I used gettext_lazy. Let me try with ugettext_lazy.

Comment: Did you wrap all the text that needs to be translated with gettext? also did you change the browser language to see if the translation will load. Did you check the po files to see if the translations were just fuzzy?

Comment: You mean like wrap all text with gettext before the command "makemessages" or after? I did both and none worked. I tried changing the browser language too, but nothing happened. I think the error is something about the fuzzy comments. The command "make messages" always generate a fuzzy for empty text. How can I fix that?

Comment: Finnaly did it. It was just missing the language request.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add an activate (django.utils.translation) on the view or set an Accept-Language header.